# Passing minified yaml as an argument to a kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

Here's a simplified version of a kubernetes job YAML config I use commonly:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mycontainer
        image: me/mycontainer:latest
        command: ["bash", "-c"]
        args:
          - python -u myscript.py
              --param1 abc
              --param2 xyz
```

The above works great, and is easy to maintain and read. But now one of my parameters needs some minified YAML:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mycontainer
        image: me/mycontainer:latest
        command: ["bash", "-c"]
        args:
          - python -u myscript.py
              --param_minified_yaml "{key: value}"
```

This bit of embedded minified yaml is being parsed by `kubectl` and causing: `error: error parsing STDIN: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 26: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

How can the embedded yaml in `args:` be escaped such that it's passed as a pure text argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the minified yaml (or the args string in general) does not include single quotes, you can wrap the whole command line in them:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mycontainer
        image: me/mycontainer:latest
        command: ["bash", "-c"]
        args:
          - 'python -u myscript.py
              --param_minified_yaml "{key: value}"'
```

If the arg string contains includes single quotes, the args string can be passed as a [YAML multiline string](https://yaml-multiline.info/):

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mycontainer
        image: me/mycontainer:latest
        command: ["bash", "-c"]
        args:
          - >-
            python -u myscript.py
            --param_minified_yaml "{key: 'value'}"
```

Comment: Watch the indentation of the block text carefully, adding extra spaces to the `--param_minified_yaml` as I had in the original example will add newline characters. That took me a few minutes to work out. Other than that this works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [block scalar](https://yaml-multiline.info/) here:

```yaml
        args:
          - >
            python -u myscript.py
              --param_minified_yaml "{key: value}"
```

Try the different scalar formats in a [yaml validator or converter](https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json) to learn about their differences.

Answer (score 0):

The `bash -c` wrapper forces the entire actual command into a single argument, and then leads to problems around escaping and quoting.  Unless you actually need to invoke a shell (to interpolate environment variables perhaps) it's better to remove it.  Then the `command:` is a list of words; you are responsible for breaking up the command into individual words, but conversely, you can use any valid YAML syntax for each individual word.

So here I might write:

```yaml
command:
  - python
  - -u
  - myscript.py
  - --param_minified_yaml
  - '{key: value}'         # in quotes, so it is a YAML string
```

Any of the syntactic variations suggested in other answers work, and you can mix and match on a per-argument basis.

```yaml
command:
  - ...
  - --param_minified_yaml
  - >-                     # block scalar syntax, again makes a string
      {key: value}
```